# Virtual functions mechanism implementation

Tags: c++, polymorphism, vptr

first:
I read somewhere that the mechanism of virtual functions is undefined. i.e. that mean that every compiler can impelement it differently. But, every text that I found about virtual function mechanisn talk about VTBL and VPTR.

Is there another virtual function mechanism implementations? Could you bring some examples?

second:
What is the differences between VTBL implementation in different languages?

Answer (score 1):

One popular alternative is [inline caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching) that, I think, originates from Smalltalk systems.

Another alternative is having a type table per polymorphic method, instead of having a polymorphic method table (VMT) per type. It requires whole program analysis, but makes efficient multiple inheritance possible. Some Eiffel compilers use such a method ([more here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/eiffel-faq/), look for "How do I implement multiple inheritance efficiently?").

The last one also mentions another method, a switch statement based approach (inspect in Eiffel ~ switch in C). SmartEiffel uses a variant of it, it makes a binary search based on the class ID. It also requires whole program analysis, but can sometimes be more efficient than VMT on current systems thanks to better instruction cache behavior. ([more here](http://smarteiffel.loria.fr/papers/papers.html), look for "Efficient Dynamic Dispatch without Virtual Function Tables").

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

[Virtual method table: Comparison with alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table#Comparison_with_alternatives)

Different compiler vendor may choose a different method... But the final implementation needs to be compliant with standard. which is this...

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf (section 10.3)

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you an example.

```
class B
{
private:
    int m_i;
public:
    void foo() { puts("B::foo"); }
    virtual void bar() { puts("B::bar"); }
};
class D : public B
{
private:
    int m_j;
public:
    virtual void bar() { puts("D::bar"); }
    virtual void asdf() { puts("D::asdf"); }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    B *pb = &d;
    pb->bar();
}
```

Most compilers implements that code as follows:

```
struct B;
struct __vtbl_B_t
{
    void (*bar)(B * const this);
};
struct B
{
    const __vtbl_B_t *__vptr;
    int m_i;
};
void B__foo(B * const this) { puts("B::foo"); }
void B__bar(B * const this) { puts("B::bar"); }

const __vtbl_B_t __vtbl_B = { B__bar };
void B__ctor(B * const this)
{
    this->__vptr = &__vtbl_B;
}

struct D;
struct __vtbl_D_t
{
    __vtbl_B_t __base;
    void (*asdf)(D * const this);
};
struct D
{
    B __base;
    int m_j;
};
void D__bar(D * const this) { puts("D::bar"); }
void D__asdf(D * const this) { puts("D::asdf"); }

__vtbl_D_t __vtbl_D = { { (void (*)(B * const))D__bar }, D__asdf };
void D__ctor(D * const this)
{
    B__ctor((B * const)this);
    this->__base.__vptr = (const __vtbl_B_t *)&__vtbl_D;
}

int main()
{
    D d;
    D__ctor(&d);

    B *pb = (B *)&d;

    (*pb->__vptr->bar)(pb);
}
```

Output:

```
D::bar
```

Even if your language is not C++, the behaviors of compilers are similiar.